# In 1 John 2:3, is εν τούτῳ ("by this") an instrumental dative or locative dative?

Tags: greek, 1-john

> Now by this we know that we know Him, if we keep His commandments. - 1 John 2:3 (NKJV)

I am new to Greek and I am not sure how to parse exactly the word **this** (Gk τούτῳ) whether it is `locative dative` or `instrumental dative`. According to biblical Greek scholar A.T. Robertson (i.e. Robertson's Word Pictures) it is `locative dative` which would mean (my own translation now) a person who really knows GOD or is in the sphere/domain of true knowledge (Gk γινώσκω) of GOD if we obey His commands.

The following is A.T. Robertson's comment on the **by this** in *1 John 2:3*

> Hereby (en toutōi). See this phrase also in 1Jn_2:5; 1Jn_3:16,
>   1Jn_3:19, 1Jn_3:24; 1Jn_4:2, 1Jn_4:13; 1Jn_5:2. That is explained by
>   the ean clause, “if we keep his commandments” (ean tērōmen,
>   condition of the third class, ean with present active subjunctive, “if
>   we keep on keeping”), the clause itself in apposition with toutōi
>   (locative case)

Now, on my own limited understanding, would it be rather `instrumental dative` since the means or agency that we could verify if someone knows GOD is his/her obedience to GOD's command?

Comment: Well, using the immediate context (vv 7-11), he was talking about loving one another as brothers/sisters in the LORD. The new (yet old) commandment to love one another is very Johannine (see John 13:34-35; 1 John 3:11, 23; 2 John 1:5). Given also the historical context it was written, John was combatting Gnostics who claimed to have special knowledge of GOD but devoid of agape love towards others thus a marker according to John of someone who does not really "know" GOD.

Comment: In this case how does locative versus instrumental affect the interpretation?

Comment: Thanks Ruminator, I did already. @PerryWebb I was just curious of the locative parsing of `en toutoi` since common sense reading on this verse alone plus the immediate context would seem to warrant instrumental rather than simply locative parsing. Interpretation may not have big impact on this case but similar situation on different passages could mean a big difference. And as a student of the Word of GOD we want to rightly divide the Word of GOD (2 Tim 2:15) to the people we are sharing His word.

Comment: As seemingly open and shut this case is I wish we had a "Big Greek" on this question because Robertson is quite respected and I am concerned we are all missing something.

Comment: I agree with you. And that's why I post here hoping someone who has really solid background in Koine Greek could help me out on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Τουτω in I John 2:3 is the prepositional dative, that is to say the word is in the dative form simply because the preposition εν is being used. Τουτω could not be expressed in Greek in any other way (correctly) in this place.

The question really concerns the preposition rather than the dative noun. Any spectrum of meaning will come from the elastic variation of the preposition. In grammatical terms, it is εν+dative that is responsible for the variation in meaning. (Not the different shades of meaning relevant to the dative form of nouns.)

Εν (which, unlike some multiple-case Greek prepositions, only ever precedes one case, namely the dative) is by far the most frequently used preposition in the New Testament, occurring 2,752 times as recorded by Daniel B Wallace in his book "Beyond the Basics" [1996, p357] in which he lists ten categories of varied shades of meaning for the preposition :

- 1.Spatial/Sphere : *in*
- 2.Temporal : *in, within, when, while, during*
- 3.Association : (often close personal relationship) : with
- 4.Cause : *because of*
- 5.Instrumental : *by, with*
- 6.Reference/Respect : *with respect to/with reference to*
- 7.Manner : *with*
- 8.Thing possessed : *with* (in the sense of *which possesses*)
- 9.Standard (=Dative of Rule) : *according to the standard of*
- 10.As an equivalent of εις (with verbs of motion)

[As an aside, Daniel B Wallace disputes that εν + dative is elastic to the point of including Personal Agency or Content meanings, see pp 373, 374.]

============================================================================

With regard to I John 2:3, the following translations have been rendered for the phrase
εν τουτω γινωσκομεν :

> ... by this we know ... EGNT literal interlinear
>
> ... hereby we do know ... KJV
>
> ... in this we know ... Young's Literal
>
> ... by this we know ... Green's Literal
>
> ... and hereby we are sure ... Tyndale
>
> ... hereby we know ... J N Darby

From the Latin Vulgate :

> ... by this we know ... Douay Rheims (Jerome/Challoner)
>
> ... in this thing we wit ... The Wycliffe

Six of the above translations are expressing the Instrumental shade of meaning of εν+dative : 'by' or 'hereby'.

Two of the above translations are expressing Content : 'in', which Daniel B Wallace disagrees is a valid rendering for εν+dative, being outside of the boundaries of the meaning.

So I, personally, would go with the six valid sources above which are within Daniel B Wallace's parameter and say that εν τουτω in this place gives the meaning of 'by this means' we know, that is 'by this instrumentality'.

So, yes, I would agree - and I think that the above indicates that authorities agree - with the OP, regarding instrumentality.

Comment: I certainly agree with your comments here that the apposition of the preposition `ἐν` together with `τούτῳ` could render this as instrumental rather than locative. I would wait for other answers though so that I could weigh in more on this matter before I will make my decision on answer acceptance. Thank you for your answer Nigel.

Comment: Understood. Good question.

Comment: I wonder if we should be looking at 9.Standard (=Dative of Rule) : "according to the standard of"?

Comment: @Ruminator That's a good point. That could be probably what A.T. Robertson meant?

Comment: I haven't looked at Robertson's entry but if he's taking it as locative I suppose he's reading it as "in the realm of commandment keeping is where the true believer distinguishes themselves and the reality of their faith". I see it as "we know" indicating that the subject is "we" so "we know x by means of y" with x being that they know God and the means being "through this - their commandment keeping".

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no formal greek education.

Comment: I would go with "Dative of Rule". BDAG doesn't seem to have such a category but Wallace is good authority.

Comment: Good answer. +1. The next two verses are *crucial*: they necessitate the understanding of 'by this can we know' (instrumental).

Comment: Yes, @SolaGratia, εν τουτω γινωσκομεν οτι εν αυτω εσμεν in I John 2:5 repeats the construction and (in my view) emphases the instrumentality. _By this we know that we are in him_.

Comment: In this case how does locative versus instrumental affect the interpretation?

Comment: @PerryWebb  I think the question is about translation, not interpretation.

Comment: One should note that Robertson assigned Greek eight cases following Sanskrit, while Wallace as most follows the physical declension of Greek having five cases.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the entire entry in BDAG (Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed.). Chicago: University of Chicago Press.) for ἐν. You will notice that in a quality lexicon such as BDAG it doesn't just provide a gloss or definition like "ἐν means 'in'" but instead lists the various ways that the word is used, with examples.

ἐν prep. w. dat. (Hom.+). For lit. s. ἀνά and εἰς, beg. For special NT uses s. AOepke, TW II 534–39. The uses of this prep. are so many and various, and oft. so easily confused, that a strictly systematic treatment is impossible. It must suffice to list the main categories, which will help establish the usage in individual cases. The earliest auditors/readers, not being inconvenienced by grammatical and lexical debates, would readily absorb the context and experience little difficulty.

① marker of a position defined as being in a location, in, among (the basic idea, Rob. 586f)

ⓐ of the space or place within which someth. is found, in: ἐν τῇ πόλει Lk 7:37. ἐν Βηθλέεμ Mt 2:1. ἐν τῇ ἐρήμῳ 3:1 (Just., D. 19, 5, cp. A I, 12, 6 ἐν ἐρημίᾳ) ἐν τῷ ἱερῷ Ac 5:42. ἐν οἴκῳ 1 Ti 3:15 and very oft. ἐν τοῖς τοῦ πατρός μου in my Father’s house Lk 2:49 and perh. Mt 20:15 (cp. Jos., Ant. 16, 302, C. Ap. 1, 118 ἐν τοῖς τοῦ Διός; PTebt 12, 3; POxy 523, 3; Tob 6:11 S; Goodsp., Probs. 81–83). ἐν τῇ ἀγορᾷ Mt 20:3. ἐν (τῷ) οὐρανῷ in heaven (Arat., Phaen. 10; Diod S 4, 61, 6; Plut., Mor. 359d τὰς ψυχὰς ἐν οὐρανῷ λάμπειν ἄστρα; Tat. 12, 2 τὰ ἄστρα τὰ ἐν αὐτῷ) Ac 2:19 (Jo 3:3); Rv 12:1; IEph 19:2.—W. quotations and accounts of the subject matter of literary works: in (Ps.-Demetr. c. 226 ὡς ἐν τῷ Εὐθυδήμῳ; Simplicius in Epict. p. 28, 37 ἐν τῷ Φαίδωνι; Ammon. Hermiae in Aristot. De Interpret. c. 9 p. 136, 20 Busse ἐν Τιμαίῳ παρειλήφαμεν=we have received as a tradition; 2 Macc 2:4; 1 Esdr 1:40; 5:48; Sir 50:27; Just., A I, 60, 1 ἐν τῷ παρὰ Πλάτωνι Τιμαίῳ) ἐν τῇ ἐπιστολῇ 1 Cor 5:9. ἐν τῷ νόμῳ Lk 24:44; J 1:45. ἐν τοῖς προφήταις Ac 13:40. ἐν Ἠλίᾳ in the story of Elijah Ro 11:2 (Just., D. 120, 3 ἐν τῷ Ἰούδα). ἐν τῷ Ὡσηέ 9:25 (Just., D. 44, 2 ἐν τῷ Ἰεζεκιήλ). ἐν Δαυίδ in the Psalter (by David is also prob.: s. 6) Hb 4:7. ἐν ἑτέρῳ προφήτῃ in another prophet B 6:14. Of inner life φανεροῦσθαι ἐν ταῖς συνειδήσεσι be made known to (your) consciences 2 Cor 5:11. ἐν τῇ καρδίᾳ Mt 5:28; 13:19; 2 Cor 11:12 et al.

ⓑ on ἐν τῷ ὄρει (X., An. 4, 3, 31; Diod S 14, 16, 2 λόφος ἐν ᾧ=a hill on which; Jos., Ant. 12, 259; Just., D. 67, 9 ἐν ὄρει Χωρήβ) J 4:20f; Hb 8:5 (Ex 25:40). ἐν τῇ ἀγορᾷ in the market Mt 20:3. ἐν τῇ ὁδῷ on the way Mt 5:25. ἐν πλαξίν on tablets 2 Cor 3:3. ἐν ταῖς γωνίαις τῶν πλατειῶν on the street corners Mt 6:5.

ⓒ within the range of, at, near (Soph., Fgm. 37 [34 N.2] ἐν παντὶ λίθῳ=near every stone; Artem. 4, 24 p. 217, 19 ἐν Τύρῳ=near Tyre; Polyaenus 8, 24, 7 ἐν τῇ νησῖδι=near the island; Diog. L. 1, 34; 85; 97 τὰ ἐν ποσίν=what is before one’s feet; Jos., Vi. 227 ἐν Χαβωλώ) ἐν τῷ γαζοφυλακείῳ (q.v.) J 8:20. ἐν τῷ Σιλωάμ near the pool of Siloam Lk 13:4. καθίζειν ἐν τῇ δεξιᾷ τινος sit at someone’s right hand (cp. 1 Esdr 4:29) Eph 1:20; Hb 1:3; 8:1.

ⓓ among, in (Hom.+; PTebt 58, 41 [111 b.c.]; Sir 16:6; 31:9; 1 Macc 4:58; 5:2; TestAbr B 9 p. 13, 27 [Stone p. 74]; Just., A I, 5, 4 ἐν βαρβάροις) ἐν τῇ γενεᾷ ταύτῃ in the generation now living Mk 8:38. ἐν τῷ γένει μου among my people Gal 1:14 (Just., D. 51, 1 al. ἐν τῷ γένει ὑμῶν). ἐν ἡμῖν Hb 13:21. ἐν τῷ ὄχλῳ in the crowd Mk 5:30 (cp. Sir 7:7). ἐν ἀλλήλοις mutually (Thu. 1, 24, 4; Just., D. 101, 3) Ro 1:12; 15:5. ἐν τοῖς ἡγεμόσιν (=among the commanding officers: Diod S 18, 61, 2; Appian, Bell. Civ. 5, 21 §84) Ἰούδα Mt 2:6 et al. ἐν ἀνθρώποις among people (as Himerius, Or. 48 [14], 11; Just., A I, 23, 3, D. 64, 7) Lk 2:14; cp. Ac 4:12.

ⓔ before, in the presence of, etc. (cp. Od. 2, 194; Eur., Andr. 359; Pla., Leg. 9, 879b; Demosth. 24, 207; Polyb. 5, 39, 6; Epict. 3, 22, 8; Appian, Maced. 18 §2 ἐν τοῖς φίλοις=in the presence of his friends; Sir 19:8; Jdth 6:2; PPetr. II, 4 [6], 16 [255/254 b.c.] δινὸν γάρ ἐστιν ἐν ὄχλῳ ἀτιμάζεσθαι=before a crowd) σοφίαν λαλοῦμεν ἐν τοῖς τελείοις in the presence of mature (i.e. spiritually sophisticated) adults 1 Cor 2:6 (cp. Simplicius in Epict. p. 131, 20 λέγειν τὰ θεωρήματα ἐν ἰδιώταις). ἐν τ. ὠσὶν ὑμῶν in your hearing Lk 4:21 (cp. Judg 17:2; 4 Km 23:2; Bar 1:3f), where the words can go linguistically just as well w. πεπλήρωται as w. ἡ γραφὴ αὕτη (this passage of scripture read in your hearing). ἐν ὀφθαλμοῖς τινος in someone’s eyes, i.e. judgment (Wsd 3:2; Sir 8:16; Jdth 3:4; 12:14; 1 Macc 1:12) Mt 21:42 (Ps 117:23). ἔν τινι in the same mng. as early as Trag. (Soph., Oed. C. 1213 ἐν ἐμοί=in my judgment, Ant. 925 ἐν θεοῖς καλά; also Pla., Prot. 337b; 343c) ἐν ἐμοί 1 Cor 14:11; possibly J 3:21 (s. 4c below) and Jd 1 belong here.—In the ‘forensic’ sense ἔν τινι can mean in someone’s court or forum (Soph., Ant. 459; Pla., Gorg. 464d, Leg. 11, 916b; Ael. Aristid. 38, 3 K.=7 p. 71 D.; 46 p. 283, 334 D.; Diod S 19, 51, 4; Ps.-Heraclit., Ep. 4, 6; but in several of these pass. the mng. does not go significantly beyond ‘in the presence of’ [s. above]) ἐν ὑμῖν 1 Cor 6:2 (by you is also tenable; s. 6 below).

ⓕ esp. to describe certain processes, inward: ἐν ἑαυτῷ to himself, i.e. in silence, διαλογίζεσθαι Mk 2:8; Lk 12:17; διαπορεῖν Ac 10:17; εἰδέναι J 6:61; λέγειν Mt 3:9; 9:21; Lk 7:49; εἰπεῖν 7:39 al.; ἐμβριμᾶσθαι J 11:38.

② marker of a state or condition, in

ⓐ of being clothed and metaphors assoc. with such condition in, with (Hdt. 2, 159; X., Mem. 3, 11, 4; Diod S 1, 12, 9; Herodian 2, 13, 3; Jdth 10:3; 1 Macc 6:35; 2 Macc 3:33) ἠμφιεσμένον ἐν μαλακοῖς dressed in soft clothes Mt 11:8. περιβάλλεσθαι ἐν ἱματίοις Rv 3:5; 4:4. ἔρχεσθαι ἐν ἐνδύμασι προβάτων come in sheep’s clothing Mt 7:15. περιπατεῖν ἐν στολαῖς walk about in long robes Mk 12:38 (Tat. 2, 1 ἐν πορφυρίδι περιπατῶν); cp. Ac 10:30; Mt 11:21; Lk 10:13. ἐν λευκοῖς in white (Artem. 2, 3; 4, 2 ἐν λευκοῖς προϊέναι; Epict. 3, 22, 1) J 20:12; Hv 4, 2, 1. Prob. corresp. ἐν σαρκί clothed in flesh (cp. Diod S 1, 12, 9 deities appear ἐν ζῴων μορφαῖς) 1 Ti 3:16; 1J 4:2; 2J 7. ἐν πάσῃ τῇ δόξῃ αὐτοῦ in all his glory Mt 6:29 (cp. 1 Macc 10:86). ἐν τ. δόξῃ τοῦ πατρός clothed in his Father’s glory 16:27; cp. 25:31; Mk 8:38; Lk 9:31.

ⓑ of other states and conditions (so freq. w. γίνομαι, εἰμί; Attic wr.; PPetr II, 11 [1], 8 [III b.c.] γράφε, ἵνα εἰδῶμεν ἐν οἷς εἶ; 39 [g], 16; UPZ 110, 176 [164 b.c.] et al.; LXX; Just., A I, 13, 2 πάλιν ἐν ἀφθαρσίᾳ γενέσθαι; 67, 6 τοῖς ἐν χρείᾳ οὖσι; Tat. 20, 1f οὐκ ἔστι γὰρ ἄπειρος ὁ οὐρανός, … πεπερασμένος δὲ καὶ ἐν τέρματι; Mel., HE 4, 26, 6 ἐν … λεηλασίᾳ ‘plundering’): ὑπάρχων ἐν βασάνοις Lk 16:23. ἐν τῷ θανάτῳ 1J 3:14. ἐν ζωῇ Ro 5:10. ἐν τοῖς δεσμοῖς Phlm 13 (Just., A II, 2, 11 ἐν δ. γενέσθαι). ἐν πειρασμοῖς 1 Pt 1:6; ἐν πολλοῖς ὢν ἀστοχήμασι AcPlCor 2:1. ἐν ὁμοιώματι σαρκός Ro 8:3. ἐν πολλῷ ἀγῶνι 1 Th 2:2. ἐν φθορᾷ in a state of corruptibility 1 Cor 15:42. ἐν ἑτοίμῳ ἔχειν 2 Cor 10:6 (cp. PEleph 10, 7 [223/222 b.c.] τ. λοιπῶν ἐν ἑτοίμῳ ὄντων; PGen 76, 8; 3 Macc 5:8); ἐν ἐκστάσει in a state of trance Ac 11:5 (opp. Just., D, 115, 3 ἐν καταστάσει ὤν). Of qualities: ἐν πίστει κ. ἀγάπῃ κ. ἁγιασμῷ 1 Ti 2:15; ἐν κακίᾳ καὶ φθόνῳ Tit 3:3; ἐν πανουργίᾳ 2 Cor 4:2; ἐν εὐσεβείᾳ καὶ σεμνότητι 1 Ti 2:2; ἐν τῇ ἀνοχῇ τοῦ θεοῦ Ro 3:26; ἐν μυστηρίῳ 1 Cor 2:7; ἐν δόξῃ Phil 4:19.

③ marker of extension toward a goal that is understood to be within an area or condition, into: ἐν is somet. used w. verbs of motion where εἰς would normally be expected (Diod S 23, 8, 1 Ἄννων ἐπέρασε ἐν Σικελίᾳ; Hero I 142, 7; 182, 4; Paus. 7, 4, 3 διαβάντες ἐν τῇ Σάμῳ; Epict. 1, 11, 32; 2, 20, 33; Aelian, VH 4, 18; Vett. Val. 210, 26; 212, 6 al., s. index; Pel.-Leg. 1, 4; 5; 2, 1; PParis 10, 2 [145 b.c.] ἀνακεχώρηκεν ἐν Ἀλεξανδρείᾳ; POxy 294, 4; BGU 22, 13; Tob 5:5 BA; 1 Macc 10:43; TestAbr B 2 p. 106, 23=Stone p. 60 [s. on the LXX Thackeray 25]; πέμψον αὐτοὺς ἐν πολέμῳ En 10:9; TestAbr A 6 p. 83, 22 [Stone p. 14] δάκρυα … ἐν τῷ νιπτῆρι πίπτοντα): εἰσέρχεσθαι Lk 9:46; Rv 11:11; ἀπάγειν GJs 6:1; ἀνάγειν 7:1; εἰσάγειν 10:1; καταβαίνειν J 5:3 (4) v.l.; ἀναβαίνειν GJs 22:13; ἀπέρχεσθαι (Diod S 23, 18, 5) Hs 1:6; ἥκειν GJs 5:1; ἀποστέλλειν 25:1. To be understood otherwise: ἐξῆλθεν ὁ λόγος ἐν ὅλῃ τῇ Ἰουδαίᾳ the word went out = spread in all Judaea Lk 7:17; likew. 1 Th 1:8. The metaphorical expr. ἐπιστρέψαι ἀπειθεῖς ἐν φρονήσει δικαίων turn the disobedient to the wisdom of the righteous Lk 1:17 is striking but consistent w. the basic sense of ἐν. S. also γίνομαι, δίδωμι, ἵστημι, καλέω, and τίθημι. ἐν μέσῳ among somet. answers to the question ‘whither’ (B-D-F §215, 3) Mt 10:16; Lk 10:3; 8:7.

④ marker of close association within a limit, in

ⓐ fig., of pers., to indicate the state of being filled w. or gripped by someth.: in someone=in one’s innermost being ἐν αὐτῷ κατοικεῖ πᾶν τὸ πλήρωμα in him dwells all the fullness Col 2:9. ἐν αὐτῷ ἐκτίσθη τὰ πάντα (prob. to be understood as local, not instrumental, since ἐν αὐ. would otherwise be identical w. διʼ αὐ. in the same vs.) everything was created in association with him 1:16 (cp. M. Ant. 4, 23 ἐν σοὶ πάντα; Herm. Wr. 5, 10; AFeuillet, NTS 12, ’65, 1–9). ἐν τῷ θεῷ κέκρυπται ἡ ζωὴ ὑμῶν your life is hid in God 3:3; cp. 2:3. Of sin in humans Ro 7:17f; cp. κατεργάζεσθαι vs. 8. Of Christ who, as a spiritual being, fills people so as to be in charge of their lives 8:10; 2 Cor 13:5, abides J 6:56, lives Gal 2:20, and takes form 4:19 in them. Of the divine word: οὐκ ἔστιν ἐν ἡμῖν 1J 1:10; μένειν ἔν τινι J 5:38; ἐνοικεῖν Col 3:16. Of God’s spirit: οἰκεῖν (ἐνοικεῖν) ἔν τινι Ro 8:9, 11; 1 Cor 3:16; 2 Ti 1:14. Of spiritual gifts 1 Ti 4:14; 2 Ti 1:6. Of miraculous powers ἐνεργεῖν ἔν τινι be at work in someone Mt 14:2; Mk 6:14; ποιεῖν ἔν τινι εὐάρεστον Hb 13:21. The same expr. of God or evil spirits, who somehow work in people: 1 Cor 12:6; Phil 2:13; Eph 2:2 al.

ⓑ of the whole, w. which the parts are closely joined: μένειν ἐν τῇ ἀμπέλῳ remain in the vine J 15:4. ἐν ἑνὶ σώματι μέλη πολλὰ ἔχομεν in one body we have many members Ro 12:4. κρέμασθαι ἔν τινι depend on someth. Mt 22:40.

ⓒ esp. in Paul. or Joh. usage, to designate a close personal relation in which the referent of the ἐν-term is viewed as the controlling influence: under the control of, under the influence of, in close association with (cp. ἐν τῷ Δαυιδ εἰμί 2 Km 19:44): of Christ εἶναι, μένειν ἐν τῷ πατρί (ἐν τῷ θεῷ) J 10:38; 14:10f (difft. CGordon, ‘In’ of Predication or Equivalence: JBL 100, ’81, 612f); and of Christians 1J 3:24; 4:13, 15f; be or abide in Christ J 14:20; 15:4f; μένειν ἐν τῷ υἱῷ καὶ ἐν τῷ πατρί 1J 2:24. ἔργα ἐν θεῷ εἰργασμένα done in communion with God J 3:21 (but s. 1e above).—In Paul the relation of the individual to Christ is very oft. expressed by such phrases as ἐν Χριστῷ, ἐν κυρίῳ etc., also vice versa (FNeugebauer, NTS 4, ’57/58, 124–38; AWedderburn, JSNT 25, ’85, 83–97) ἐν ἐμοὶ Χριστός Gal 2:20, but here in the sense of a above.—See, e.g., Dssm., D. ntl. Formel ‘in Christo Jesu’ 1892; EWeber, D. Formel ‘in Chr. Jesu’ u. d. paul. Christusmystik: NKZ 31, 1920, 213ff; LBrun, Zur Formel ‘in Chr. Jesus’ im Phil: Symbolae Arctoae 1, 1922, 19–37; MHansen, Omkring Paulus-Formeln ‘i Kristus’: TK 4/10, 1929, 135–59; HBöhlig, ʼΕν κυρίῳ: GHeinrici Festschr. 1914, 170–75; OSchmitz, D. Christusgemeinschaft d. Pls2 ’56; AWikenhauser, D. Christusmystik d. Pls2 ’56; KMittring, Heilswirklichkeit b. Pls; Beitrag z. Verständnis der unio cum Christo in d. Plsbriefen 1929; ASchweitzer, D. Mystik d. Ap. Pls 1930 (Eng. tr., WMontgomery, The Myst. of Paul the Ap., ’31); WSchmauch, In Christus ’35; BEaston, Pastoral Ep. ’47, 210f; FBüchsel, ‘In Chr.’ b. Pls: ZNW 42, ’49, 141–58. Also HKorn, D. Nachwirkungen d. Christusmystik d. Pls in den Apost. Vätern, diss. Berlin 1928; EAndrews, Interpretation 6, ’52, 162–77; H-LParisius, ZNW 49, ’58, 285–88 (10 ‘forensic’ passages); JAllan, NTS 5, ’58/59, 54–62 (Eph), ibid. 10, ’63, 115–21 (pastorals); FNeugebauer, In Christus, etc. ’61; MDahl, The Resurrection of the Body (1 Cor 15) ’62, 110–13.—Paul has the most varied expressions for this new life-principle: life in Christ Ro 6:11, 23; love in Christ 8:39; grace, which is given in Christ 1 Cor 1:4; freedom in Chr. Gal 2:4; blessing in Chr. 3:14; unity in Chr. vs. 28. στήκειν ἐν κυρίῳ stand firm in the Lord Phil 4:1; εὑρεθῆναι ἐν Χ. be found in Christ 3:9; εἶναι ἐν Χ. 1 Cor 1:30; οἱ ἐν Χ. Ro 8:1.—1 Pt 5:14; κοιμᾶσθαι ἐν Χ., ἀποθνῄσκειν ἐν κυρίῳ 1 Cor 15:18.—Rv 14:13; ζῳοποιεῖσθαι 1 Cor 15:22.—The formula is esp. common w. verbs that denote a conviction, hope, etc. πεποιθέναι Gal 5:10; Phil 1:14; 2 Th 3:4. παρρησίαν ἔχειν Phlm 8. πέπεισμαι Ro 14:14. ἐλπίζειν Phil 2:19. καύχησιν ἔχειν Ro 15:17; 1 Cor 15:31. τὸ αὐτὸ φρονεῖν Phil 4:2. ὑπακούειν Eph 6:1. λαλεῖν 2 Cor 2:17; 12:19. ἀλήθειαν λέγειν Ro 9:1. λέγειν καὶ μαρτύρεσθαι Eph 4:17. But also apart fr. such verbs, in numerous pass. it is used w. verbs and nouns of the most varied sort, often without special emphasis, to indicate the scope within which someth. takes place or has taken place, or to designate someth. as being in close assoc. w. Christ, and can be rendered, variously, in connection with, in intimate association with, keeping in mind ἁγιάζεσθαι 1 Cor 1:2, or ἅγιος ἐν Χ. Phil 1:1; ἀσπάζεσθαί τινα 1 Cor 16:19. δικαιοῦσθαι Gal 2:17. κοπιᾶν Ro 16:12. παρακαλεῖν 1 Th 4:1. προσδέχεσθαί τινα Ro 16:2; Phil 2:29. χαίρειν 3:1; 4:4, 10. γαμηθῆναι ἐν κυρίῳ marry in the Lord=marry a Christian 1 Cor 7:39. προϊστάμενοι ὑμῶν ἐν κυρίῳ your Christian leaders (in the church) 1 Th 5:12 (but s. προΐστημι 1 and 2).—εὐάρεστος Col 3:20. νήπιος 1 Cor 3:1. φρόνιμος 4:10. παιδαγωγοί vs. 15. ὁδοί vs. 17. Hence used in periphrasis for ‘Christian’ οἱ ὄντες ἐν κυρίῳ Ro 16:11; ἄνθρωπος ἐν Χ. 2 Cor 12:2; αἱ ἐκκλησίαι αἱ ἐν Χ. Gal 1:22; 1 Th 2:14; νεκροὶ ἐν Χ. 4:16; ἐκλεκτός Ro 16:13. δόκιμος vs. 10. δέσμιος Eph 4:1. πιστὸς διάκονος 6:21; ἐν Χ. γεννᾶν τινα become someone’s parent in the Christian life 1 Cor 4:15. τὸ ἔργον μου ὑμεῖς ἐστε ἐν κυρίῳ 9:1.—The use of ἐν πνεύματι as a formulaic expression is sim.: ἐν πν. εἶναι be under the impulsion of the spirit, i.e. the new self, as opposed to ἐν σαρκί under the domination of the old self Ro 8:9; cp. ἐν νόμῳ 2:12. λαλεῖν speak under divine inspiration 1 Cor 12:3. ἐγενόμην ἐν πνεύματι I was in a state of inspiration Rv 1:10; 4:2; opp. ἐν ἑαυτῷ γενόμενος came to himself Ac 12:11 (cp. X., An. 1, 5, 17 et al.).—The expr. ἐν πν. εἶναι is also used to express the idea that someone is under the special infl. of a good or even an undesirable spirit: Mt 22:43; Mk 12:36; Lk 2:27; 1 Cor 12:3; Rv 17:3; 21:10. ἄνθρωπος ἐν πν. ἀκαθάρτῳ (ὤν) Mk 1:23 (s. GBjörck, ConNeot 7, ’42, 1–3).—ἐν τῷ πονηρῷ κεῖσθαι be in the power of the evil one 1J 5:19. οἱ ἐν νόμῳ those who are subject to the law Ro 3:19. ἐν τῷ Ἀδὰμ ἀποθνῄσκειν die because of a connection w. Adam 1 Cor 15:22.—On the formula ἐν ὀνόματι (Χριστοῦ) s. ὄνομα 1, esp. dγג. The OT is the source of the expr. ὀμνύναι ἔν τινι swear by someone or someth. (oft. LXX) Mt 5:34ff; 23:16, 18ff; Rv 10:6; παραγγέλλομέν σοι ἐν Ἰησοῦ Ac 19:14 v.l. The usage in ὁμολογεῖν ἔν τινι acknowledge someone Mt 10:32; Lk 12:8 (s. ὁμολογέω 4b) is Aramaic.

**⑤ marker introducing means or instrument, with, a construction that begins w. Homer (many examples of instrumental ἐν in Radermacher’s edition of Ps.-Demetr., Eloc. p. 100; Reader, Polemo p. 258) but whose wide currency in our lit. is partly caused by the infl. of the LXX, and its similarity to the Hebr. constr. w. בְּ (B-D-F §219; Mlt. 104; Mlt-H. 463f; s. esp. M-M p. 210).**

ⓐ it can serve to introduce persons or things that accompany someone to secure an objective: ‘along with’

α. pers., esp. of a military force, w. blending of associative (s. 4) and instrumental idea (1 Macc 1:17; 7:14, 28 al.): ἐν δέκα χιλιάσιν ὑπαντῆσαι meet, w. 10,000 men Lk 14:31 (cp. 1 Macc 4:6, 29 συνήντησεν αὐτοῖς Ἰούδας ἐν δέκα χιλιάσιν ἀνδρῶν). ἦλθεν ἐν μυριάσιν αὐτοῦ Jd 14 (cp. Jdth 16:3 ἦλθεν ἐν μυριάσι δυνάμεως αὐτοῦ).

β. impers. (oft. LXX; PTebt 41, 5 [c. 119 b.c.]; 16, 14 [114 b.c.]; 45, 17 al., where people rush into the village or the house ἐν μαχαίρῃ, ἐν ὅπλοις). (Just., D. 86, 6 τῆς ἀξίνης, ἐν ἧ πεπορευμένοι ἦσαν … κόψαι ξύλα) ἐν ῥάβδῳ ἔρχεσθαι come with a stick (as a means of discipline) 1 Cor 4:21 (cp. Lucian, Dial. Mort. 23, 3 Ἑρμῆν καθικόμενον ἐν τῇ ῥάβδῳ; Gen 32:11; 1 Km 17:43; 1 Ch 11:23; Dssm., B 115f [BS 120]). ἐν πληρώματι εὐλογίας with the full blessing Ro 15:29. ἐν τῇ βασιλείᾳ αὐτοῦ Mt 16:28. ἐν αἵματι Hb 9:25 (cp. Mi 6:6). ἐν τῷ ὕδατι καὶ ἐν τῷ αἵματι 1J 5:6. ἐν πνεύματι καὶ δυνάμει τοῦ Ἠλίου equipped w. the spirit and power of Elijah Lk 1:17. φθάνειν ἐν τῷ εὐαγγελίῳ come with the preaching of the gospel 2 Cor 10:14. μὴ ἐν ζύμῃ παλαιᾷ not burdened w. old leaven 1 Cor 5:8.

ⓑ it can serve to express means or instrumentality in terms of location for a specific action (cp. TestAbr A 12 p. 91, 5f [Stone p. 30] κρατῶν ἐν τῇ χειρὶ αὐτοῦ ζυγόν; Tat. 9, 2 οἱ ἐν τοῖς πεσσοῖς ἀθύροντες ‘those who play w. gaming pieces’ [as, e.g., in backgammon]): κατακαίειν ἐν πυρί Rv 17:16 (cp. Bar 1:2; 1 Esdr 1:52; 1 Macc 5:5 al.; as early as Il. 24, 38; cp. POxy 2747, 74; Aelian, HA 14, 15. Further, the ἐν Rv 17:16 is not textually certain). ἐν ἅλατι ἁλίζειν, ἀρτύειν Mt 5:13; Mk 9:50; Lk 14:34 (s. M-M p. 210; WHutton, ET 58, ’46/47, 166–68). ἐν τῷ αἵματι λευκαίνειν Rv 7:14. ἐν αἵματι καθαρίζειν Hb 9:22. ἐν ῥομφαίᾳ ἀποκτείνειν kill with the sword Rv 6:8 (1 Esdr 1:50; 1 Macc 2:9; cp. 3:3; Jdth 16:4; ἀπολεῖ ἐν ῥομφαίᾳ En 99:16; 4 [6] Esdr [POxy 1010] ἐν ῥ. πεσῇ … πεσοῦνται ἐν μαχαίρῃ; cp. Lucian, Hist. Conscrib. 12 ἐν ἀκοντίῳ φονεύειν). ἐν μαχαίρῃ πατάσσειν Lk 22:49 (διχοτομήσατε … ἐν μ. GrBar 16:3); ἐν μ. ἀπόλλυσθαι perish by the sword Mt 26:52. ποιμαίνειν ἐν ῥάβδῳ σιδηρᾷ Rv 2:27; 12:5; 19:15 (s. ποιμαίνω 2aγ and cp. PGM 36, 109). καταπατεῖν τι ἐν τοῖς ποσίν tread someth. w. the feet Mt 7:6 (cp. Sir 38:29). δύο λαοὺς βλέπω ἐν τοῖς ὀφθαλμοῖς μου I see two peoples with my eyes GJs 17:2 (ἐν ὀφθαλμοῖσιν ὀρᾶν=see with the eyes: cp. Il. 1, 587; Od. 8, 459; Callinus [VII b.c.], Fgm. 1, 20 Diehl2). ποιεῖν κράτος ἐν βραχίονι do a mighty deed w. one’s arm Lk 1:51 (cp. Sir 38:30); cp. 11:20. δικαιοῦσθαι ἐν τῷ αἵματι be justified by the blood Ro 5:9. ἐν ἁγιασμῷ πνεύματος 2 Th 2:13; 1 Pt 1:2; ἐν τ. παρακλήσει 2 Cor 7:7. εὐλογεῖν ἐν εὐλογίᾳ Eph 1:3. λαλοῦντες ἑαυτοῖς ἐν ψάλμοις 5:19. ἀσπάσασθαι … ἐν εὐχῇ greet w. prayer GJs 24:1. Of intellectual process γινώσκειν ἔν τινι know or recognize by someth. (cp. Thuc. 7, 11, 1 ἐν ἐπιστολαῖς ἴστε; Sir 4:24; 11:28; 26:29) J 13:35; 1J 3:19; cp. ἐν τῇ κλάσει τοῦ ἄρτου in the breaking of bread Lk 24:35 (s. 10c).—The ἐν which takes the place of the gen. of price is also instrumental ἠγόρασας ἐν τῷ αἵματί σου Rv 5:9 (cp. 1 Ch 21:24 ἀγοράζω ἐν ἀργυρίῳ).—ἐν ᾧ whereby Ro 14:21.—The idiom ἀλλάσσειν, μεταλλάσσειν τι ἔν τινι exchange someth. for someth. else Ro 1:23, 25 (cp. Ps 105:20) is not un-Greek (Soph., Ant. 945 Danaë had to οὐράνιον φῶς ἀλλάξαι ἐν χαλκοδέτοις αὐλαῖς=change the heavenly light for brass-bound chambers).

⑥ marker of agency: with the help of (Diod S 19, 46, 4 ἐν τοῖς μετέχουσι τοῦ συνεδρίου=with the help of the members of the council; Philostrat., Vi. Apoll. 7, 9 p. 259, 31 ἐν ἐκείνῳ ἑαλωκότες) ἐν τῷ ἄρχοντι τ. δαιμονίων ἐκβάλλει τὰ δαιμόνια Mt 9:34. ἐν ἑτερογλώσσοις λαλεῖν 1 Cor 14:21. κρίνειν τ. οἰκουμένην ἐν ἀνδρί Ac 17:31 (cp. SIG2 850, 8 [173/172 b.c.] κριθέντω ἐν ἄνδροις τρίοις; Synes., Ep. 91 p. 231b ἐν ἀνδρί); perh. 1 Cor 6:2 (s. 1e); ἀπολύτρωσις ἐν Χρ. redemption through Christ Ro 3:24 (cp. ἐν αὐτῷ σωθήσεσθε Just., A I, 60, 3).

⑦ marker of circumstance or condition under which someth. takes place: ἐν ᾧ κρίνεις Ro 2:1 (but s. B-D-F §219, 2); ἐν ᾧ δοκιμάζει 14:22; ἐν ᾧ καυχῶνται 2 Cor 11:12; ἐν ᾧ τις τολμᾷ 11:21; ἐν ᾧ καταλαλοῦσιν whereas they slander 1 Pt 2:12, cp. 3:16 (on these Petrine pass. s. also ὅς 1k); ἐν ᾧ ξενίζονται in view of your changed attitude they consider it odd 4:4. ἐν ᾧ in 3:19 may similarly refer to a changed circumstance, i.e. from death to life (WDalton, Christ’s Proclamation to the Spirits, ’65, esp. 135–42: ‘in this sphere, under this influence’ [of the spirit]). Other possibilities: as far as this is concerned: πνεῦμα· ἐν ᾧ spirit; as which (FZimmermann, APF 11, ’35, 174 ‘meanwhile’ [indessen]; BReicke, The Disobedient Spirits and Christian Baptism, ’46, 108–15: ‘on that occasion’=when he died).—Before a substantive inf. (oft. LXX; s. KHuber, Unters. über den Sprachchar. des griech. Lev., diss. Zürich 1916, 83): in that w. pres. inf. (POxy 743, 35 [2 b.c.] ἐν τῷ δέ με περισπᾶσθαι οὐκ ἠδυνάσθην συντυχεῖν Ἀπολλωνίῳ; Just., D. 10, 3 ἐν τῷ μήτε σάββατα τηρεῖν μήτε …) βασανιζομένους ἐν τῷ ἐλαύνειν as they were having rough going in the waves=having a difficult time making headway Mk 6:48. ἐθαύμαζον ἐν τῷ χρονίζειν … αὐτόν they marveled over his delay Lk 1:21. ἐν τῷ τὴν χεῖρα ἐκτείνειν σε in that you extend your hand Ac 4:30; cp. 3:26; Hb 8:13. W. aor. inf. ἐν τῷ ὑποτάξαι αὐτῷ τὰ πάντα Hb 2:8. Somet. the circumstantial and temporal (s. 7 and 10) uses are so intermingled that it is difficult to decide between them; so in some of the pass. cited above, and also Hv 1, 1, 8 et al. (B-D-F §404, 3; Rob. 1073).—WHutton, Considerations for the Translation of ἐν, Bible Translator 9, ’58, 163–70; response by NTurner, ibid. 10, ’59, 113–20.—On ἐν w. article and inf. s. ISoisalon-Soininen, Die Infinitive in der LXX, ’65, 80ff.

⑧ marker denoting the object to which someth. happens or in which someth. shows itself, or by which someth. is recognized, to, by, in connection with: ζητεῖν τι ἔν τινι require someth. in the case of someone 1 Cor 4:2; cp. ἐν ἡμῖν μάθητε so that you might learn in connection w. us vs. 6. Cp. Phil 1:30. ἵνα οὕτως γένηται ἐν ἐμοί that this may be done in my case 1 Cor 9:15 (Just., D. 77, 3 τοῦτο γενόμενον ἐν τῷ ἡμετέρῳ Χριστῷ). ἐδόξαζον ἐν ἐμοὶ τὸν θεόν perh. they glorified God in my case Gal 1:24, though because of me and for me are also possible. μήτι ἐν ἐμοὶ ἀνεκεφαλαιώθη ἡ ἱστορία GJs 13:1 (s. ἀνακεφαλαιόω 1). ποιεῖν τι ἔν τινι do someth. to (with) someone (Epict., Ench. 33, 12; Ps.-Lucian, Philopatr. 18 μὴ ἑτεροῖόν τι ποιήσῃς ἐν ἐμοί; Gen 40:14; Jdth 7:24; 1 Macc 7:23) Mt 17:12; Lk 23:31. ἐργάζεσθαί τι ἔν τινι Mk 14:6. ἔχειν τι ἔν τινι have someth. in someone J 3:15 (but ἐν αὐτῷ is oft. constr. w. πιστεύων, cp. v.l.); cp. 14:30 (s. BNoack, Satanas u. Soteria ’48, 92). ἵνα δικαιοσύνης ναὸν ἐν τῷ ἰδίῳ σώματι ἀναδείξῃ AcPlCor 2:17 (s. ἀναδείκνυμι 1).—For the ordinary dat. (Diod S 3, 51, 4 ἐν ἀψύχῳ ἀδύνατον=it is impossible for a lifeless thing; Ael. Aristid. 49, 15 K.=25 p. 492 D.: ἐν Νηρίτῳ θαυμαστὰ ἐνεδείξατο=[God] showed wonderful things to N.; 53 p. 629 D.: οὐ γὰρ ἐν τοῖς βελτίστοις εἰσὶ παῖδες, ἐν δὲ πονηροτάτοις οὐκέτι=it is not the case that the very good have children, and the very bad have none [datives of possession]; 54 p. 653 D.: ἐν τ. φαύλοις θετέον=to the bad; EpJer 66 ἐν ἔθνεσιν; Aesop, Fab. 19, 8 and 348a, 5 v.l. Ch.) ἀποκαλύψαι τὸν υἱὸν αὐτοῦ ἐν ἐμοί Gal 1:16. φανερόν ἐστιν ἐν αὐτοῖς Ro 1:19 (Aesop 15c, 11 Ch. τ. φανερὸν ἐν πᾶσιν=evident to all). ἐν ἐμοὶ βάρβαρος (corresp. to τῷ λαλοῦντι βάρβ.) 1 Cor 14:11 (Amphis Com. [IV b.c.] 21 μάταιός ἐστιν ἐν ἐμοί). δεδομένον ἐν ἀνθρώποις Ac 4:12. θεῷ … ἐν ἀνθρώποις Lk 2:14.—Esp. w. verbs of striking against: προσκόπτω, πταίω, σκανδαλίζομαι; s. these entries.

⑨ marker of cause or reason, because of, on account of (PParis 28, 13=UPZ 48, 12f [162/161 b.c.] διαλυόμενοι ἐν τῷ λιμῷ; Ps 30:11; 1 Macc 16:3 ἐν τῷ ἐλέει; 2 Macc 7:29; Sir 33:17)

ⓐ gener. ἁγιάζεσθαι ἔν τινι Hb 10:10; 1 Cor 7:14. ἐν τ. ἐπιθυμίαις τῶν καρδιῶν Ro 1:24; perh. ἐν Ἰσαὰκ κληθήσεταί σοι σπέρμα 9:7; Hb 11:18 (both Gen 21:12). ἐν τῇ πολυλογίᾳ αὐτῶν because of their many words Mt 6:7. ἐν τούτῳ πιστεύομεν this is the reason why we believe J 16:30; cp. Ac 24:16; 1 Cor 4:4 (Just., D. 68, 7 οὐχὶ καὶ ἐν τούτῳ δυσωπήσω ὑμᾶς μὴ πείθεσθαι τοῖς διδασκάλοις ὑμῶν=‘surely you will be convinced by this [argument] to lose confidence in your teachers, won’t you?’); perh. 2 Cor 5:2. Sim., of the occasion: ἔφυγεν ἐν τῷ λόγῳ τούτῳ at this statement Ac 7:29; cp. 8:6. W. attraction ἐν ᾧ = ἐν τούτῳ ὅτι for the reason that = because Ro 8:3; Hb 2:18; 6:17.

ⓑ w. verbs that express feeling or emotion, to denote that toward which the feeling is directed; so: εὐδοκεῖν (εὐδοκία), εὐφραίνεσθαι, καυχᾶσθαι, χαίρειν et al.

⑩ marker of a period of time, in, while, when

ⓐ indicating an occurrence or action within which, at a certain point, someth. occurs Mt 2:1. ἐν ταῖς ἡμέραις ἐκείναις 3:1. ἐν τῷ ἑξῆς afterward Lk 7:11. ἐν τῷ μεταξύ meanwhile (PTebt 72, 190; PFlor 36, 5) J 4:31. in the course of, within ἐν τρισὶν ἡμέραις (X., Ages. 1, 34; Diod S 13, 14, 2; 20, 83, 4; Arrian, Anab. 4, 6, 4 ἐν τρισὶν ἡμέραις; Aelian, VH 1, 6; IPriene 9, 29; GDI 1222, 4 [Arcadia] ἰν ἁμέραις τρισί; EpArist 24; Demetr.: 722 Fgm. 1:3 Jac.) Mt 27:40; J 2:19f.

ⓑ point of time when someth. occurs ἐν ἡμέρᾳ κρίσεως Mt 11:22 (En 10:6; Just., D. 38, 2; Tat. 12, 4). ἐν τῇ ἐσχάτῃ ἡμέρᾳ J 6:44; 11:24; 12:48; cp. 7:37. ἐν ἐκείνῃ τῇ ὥρᾳ Mt 8:13; 10:19; cp. 7:22; J 4:53. ἐν σαββάτῳ 12:2; J 7:23. ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ J 11:9 (opp. ἐν τῇ νυκτί vs. 10). ἐν τῷ δευτέρῳ on the second visit Ac 7:13. ἐν τῇ παλιγγενεσίᾳ in the new age Mt 19:28. ἐν τῇ παρουσίᾳ 1 Cor 15:23; 1 Th 2:19; 3:13; Phil 2:12 (here, in contrast to the other pass., there is no reference to the second coming of Christ.—Just., D. 31, 1 ἐν τῇ ἐνδόξῳ γινομένῃ αὐτοῦ παρουσίᾳ; 35, 8; 54, 1 al.); 1J 2:28. ἐν τῇ ἀναστάσει in the resurrection Mt 22:28; Mk 12:23; Lk 14:14; 20:33; J 11:24 (Just., D. 45, 2 ἐν τῇ τῶν νεκρῶν ἀναστάσει). ἐν τῇ ἐσχάτῃ σάλπιγγι at the last trumpet-call 1 Cor 15:52. ἐν τῇ ἀποκαλύψει at the appearance of Jesus/Christ (in the last days) 2 Th 1:7; 1 Pt 1:7, 13; 4:13.

ⓒ to introduce an activity whose time is given when, while, during (Diod S 23, 12, 1 ἐν τοῖς τοιούτοις=in the case of this kind of behavior) ἐν τῇ προσευχῇ when (you) pray Mt 21:22. ἐν τῇ στάσει during the revolt Mk 15:7. ἐν τῇ διδαχῇ in the course of his teaching Mk 4:2; 12:38. If Lk 24:35 belongs here, the sense would be on the occasion of, when (but s. 5b). ἐν αὐτῷ in it (the preaching of the gospel) Eph 6:20. γρηγοροῦντες ἐν αὐτῇ (τῇ προσευχῇ) while you are watchful in it Col 4:2. Esp. w. the pres. inf. used substantively: ἐν τῷ σπείρειν while (he) sowed Mt 13:4; Mk 4:4; cp. 6:48 (s. 7 above and βασανίζω); ἐν τῷ καθεύδειν τοὺς ἀνθρώπους while people were asleep Mt 13:25; ἐν τῷ κατηγορεῖσθαι αὐτόν during the accusations against him 27:12. W. the aor. inf. the meaning is likewise when. Owing to the fundamental significance of the aor. the action is the focal point (s. Rob. 1073, opp. B-D-F §404) ἐν τῷ γενέσθαι τὴν φωνήν Lk 9:36. ἐν τῷ ἐπανελθεῖν αὐτόν 19:15. ἐν τῷ εἰσελθεῖν αὐτούς 9:34.—W. ἐν ᾦ while, as long as (Soph., Trach. 929; Cleanthes [IV/III b.c.] Stoic. I p. 135, 1 [Diog. L. 7, 171]; Demetr.: 722 Fgm. 1, 11 Jac.; Plut., Mor. 356c; Arrian, Anab. 6, 12, 1; Pamprepios of Panopolis [V a.d.] 1, 22 [ed. HGerstinger, SBWienAk 208/3, 1928]) Mk 2:19; Lk 5:34; 24:44 D; J 5:7.

⑪ marker denoting kind and manner, esp. functioning as an auxiliary in periphrasis for adverbs (Kühner-G. I 466): ἐν δυνάμει w. power, powerfully Mk 9:1; Ro 1:4; Col 1:29; 2 Th 1:11; ἐν δικαιοσύνῃ justly Ac 17:31; Rv 19:11 (cp. Just., A II, 4, 3 and D. 16, 3; 19, 2 ἐν δίκῃ). ἐν χαρᾷ joyfully Ro 15:32. ἐν ἐκτενείᾳ earnestly Ac 26:7. ἐν σπουδῇ zealously Ro 12:8. ἐν χάριτι graciously Gal 1:6; 2 Th 2:16. ἐν (πάσῃ) παρρησίᾳ freely, openly J 7:4; 16:29; Phil 1:20. ἐν πάσῃ ἀσφαλείᾳ Ac 5:23. ἐν τάχει (PHib 47, 35 [256 b.c.] ἀπόστειλον ἐν τάχει) Lk 18:8; Ro 16:20; Rv 1:1; 22:6. ἐν μυστηρίῳ 1 Cor 2:7 (belongs prob. not to σοφία, but to λαλοῦμεν: in the form of a secret; cp. Polyb. 23, 3, 4; 26, 7, 5; Just., D. 63, 2 Μωυσῆς … ἐν παραβολῇ λέγων; 68, 6 εἰρήμενον … ἐν μυστηρίῳ; Diod S 17, 8, 5 ἐν δωρεαῖς λαβόντες=as gifts; 2 Macc 4:30 ἐν δωρεᾷ=as a gift; Sir 26:3; Polyb. 28, 17, 9 λαμβάνειν τι ἐν φερνῇ). Of the norm: ἐν μέτρῳ ἑνὸς ἑκάστου μέρους acc. to the measure of each individual part Eph 4:16. On 1 Cor 1:21 s. AWedderburn, ZNW 64, ’73, 132–34.

⑫ marker of specification or substance: w. adj. πλούσιος ἐν ἐλέει Eph 2:4; cp. Tit 2:3; Js 1:8.—of substance consisting in (BGU 72, 11 [191 a.d.] ἐξέκοψαν πλεῖστον τόπον ἐν ἀρούραις πέντε) τὸν νόμον τῶν ἐντολῶν ἐν δόγμασιν Eph 2:15. ἐν μηδενὶ λειπόμενοι Js 1:4 (contrast Just., A I, 67, 6 τοῖς ἐν χρείᾳ οὖσι). Hb 13:21a.—amounting to (BGU 970, 14=Mitt-Wilck. II/2, 242, 14f [177 a.d.] προσηνενκάμην αὐτῷ προοῖκα ἐν δραχμαῖς ἐννακοσίαις) πᾶσαν τὴν συγγένειαν ἐν ψυχαῖς ἑβδομήκοντα πέντε Ac 7:14.—Very rarely for the genitive (Philo Mech. 75, 29 τὸ ἐν τῷ κυλίνδρῳ κοίλασμα; EpArist 31 ἡ ἐν αὐτοῖς θεωρία = ἡ αὐτῶν θ.; cp. 29; Tat. 18, 1 πᾶν τὸ ἐν αὐτῇ εἶδος) ἡ δωρεὰ ἐν χάριτι the free gift in beneficence or grace Ro 5:15.—DELG. LfgrE s.v. ἐν col. 569 (lit. esp. early Greek). M-M. TW.

I highlighted usage ⑤ which I think may be the sense in which we should understand 1 John 2:3.

Presenting the whole BDAG entry might appear to be overkill but I thought it would be profitable to make it available for educational purposes. It is very instructive to see how complicated the simple use of of a preposition can be and how one might go about identifying the meaning intended by the author.

Of course, in this situation it might be most helpful to look at Wallace ("Beyond the Basics" [1996, p357]) who offers the following categorization:

> 9.Standard (=Dative of Rule) : according to the standard of

See also:  http://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%90%CE%BD

Comment: I notice that there are several references to Robertson in the BDAG entry!

Comment: Perhaps you could cut this down to a couple of choice definitions from the entry and still illustrate your point? Otherwise this likely will get flagged for copyright

Comment: I normally work from the Logos app which automatically does the proper crediting of the copyrighted material but am on a Chromebook at the moment and limited to the online version on Biblia.com  If properly cited does it still violate copyright? I hope to have my Windows machine back up soon and I can fix the citation. If it gets deleted for copyright I would expect an indication of the law broken. I'm pretty sure you can cite and entry in BDAG.

Comment: Yes, citing BDAG is obviously quite common. But excerpting it like this is different from citing it. There's no precise definition of "fair use", but a lot of publications try to observe a 200-300 word limit when copying from another work.

Comment: Based on this, I don't see anything to worry about:  https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html

Comment: Also, I'm a walking, talking advertiser and promoter of BDAG on this site so I think they would be happy about it!